# Re-use tests between packages in Stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm curious if it's possible to expose test folder of one package, so another package in multi-package Stack setup could re-use test functions & instances:

`second-package-test -> dependsOn -> first-package-test`

**The first package** has the following lines in `package.yaml`:

```
tests:
  first-package-test:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
      - -threaded
      - -rtsopts
      - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
      - first-package
      - hspec
      - QuickCheck
      - quickcheck-instances
      - quickcheck-classes
```

And the **second package** that should rely on the first one has the following setup:

stack.yaml contains:

```
extra-deps:
  - ../first-package <-- it seems that it imports only library, not the tests
```

package.yaml contains:

```
tests:
  second-package-test:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - second-package
    - hspec
    - QuickCheck
    - quickcheck-instances
    - quickcheck-classes
```

The root aggregation of them looks simple. stack.yaml:

```
packages:
 - first-package
 - second-package
```

I think, in theory, it's possible to create a *third* package with tests only that are exposed as a library, but wonder if there is a bit more elegant way to achieve the same thing.